# tmux' "run-shell" blocks for background processes

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, tmux

I'm using tmux version `1.9a` and I noticed that `run-shell` blocks using of any prefix-key commands until the command terminates.

To reproduce this just execute

> run-shell "sleep 10"

and try to execute any of the prefix commands (e.g. `C-b c` to create a new pane). You will notice that nothing happens. Once the command terminates the action will be executed.

For me this behaviour is undesired because the command which I want to be execute should never terminate. Is this a bug or a feature? Furthermore, any ideas on how to solve this?

In case you're wondering about the concrete use-case: I'm trying to get a `tmux` + `kerberos` setup to work properly. For this I would like to use the `ktmux` wrapper which you can find [here](https://iain.cx/src/ktmux/).

Answer (score 3):

Use `run-shell -b`:

```
With -b, the command is run in the background.
```